# Following is the final code for the function hangman and I am getting a syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Following is the final code for the function hangman and I am getting a syntax error.

```
def hangman(secretWord):

#    secretWord: string, the secret word to guess.

#    Starts up an interactive game of Hangman.

    #At the start of the game, let the user know how many 
    #  letters the secretWord contains.

    guess_count = 8
    lettersGuessed = []
    guessWord=[]
    #    * Ask the user to supply one guess (i.e. letter) per round.
    while guess_count>0:
        guessWord = input('Please Guess a letter: ')
        lettersGuessed = guessWord.lower()
        print("You have "+str(guess_count)+ " guesses left")
        print("Available letters: ",getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed)
        if isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed)==True:
           guess_count = guess_count
           print("Good guess: ",getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed))
           print("You have "+str(guess_count)+ " guesses left.")
           print("Available letter: " + str(getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed)))
        elif isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed)==False:
            print("Available letter: " + str(getAvailableLetters())
            print("Oops! That letter is not in my word: ",getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed))
            guess_count -= 1
        elif secretWord==getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
            print("Congratulations, you won!")
            break
```

Comment: Please paste the error and the code of the full function(start from def).

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one place where you do not have closing parentheses. Look at the lines above where it reports the syntax error and check for matched parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code. As bashBedlam says, this is just a case of mismatched parentheses -

```
def hangman(secretWord):
    guess_count = 8
    lettersGuessed = []
    guessWord=[]
    #    * Ask the user to supply one guess (i.e. letter) per round.
    while guess_count>0:
        guessWord = input('Please Guess a letter: ')
        lettersGuessed = guessWord.lower()
        print("You have "+str(guess_count)+ " guesses left")
        print("Available letters: ",getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed))
        if isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed)==True:
           guess_count = guess_count
           print("Good guess: ",getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed))
           print("You have "+str(guess_count)+ " guesses left.")
           print("Available letter: " + str(getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed)))
        elif isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed)==False:
            print("Available letter: " + str(getAvailableLetters()))
            print("Oops! That letter is not in my word: ",getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed))
            guess_count -= 1
        elif secretWord==getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
            print("Congratulations, you won!")
            break
```